# Plot two legends of own calculated values

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have a problem. I want to show `mean` and `median` inside my plot. But unfortunately it overwrites it (see the second code snippet). When I do `plt.legend([...,...]` the output is not what I want. How can I show the mean and median as linie and plot the legend of them both with the correct color and linestyle?

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
from numpy import random

#d = {'distance_km': [1, 100, 12, 14],}
d = {'distance_km': random.randint(100, size=(20)),}
df_calculation = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

sns.set_style("white")
# Calculation of meand and median
mean=df_calculation["distance_km"].mean()
median = df_calculation["distance_km"].median()

plt.figure(figsize=(11,5))
ax = sns.distplot(df_calculation["distance_km"],color='lightblue')
ax.axvline(mean, color='r', linestyle='--')
ax.axvline(median, color='green', linestyle='--')
plt.legend([{f'Mean = {round(df_calculation["distance_km"].mean(), 2)}':mean}, {f'Median = {round(df_calculation["distance_km"].mean(), 2)}':median}])

plt.box(False)
plt.xlabel("\n Km", fontsize = 12)
plt.ylabel("", fontsize = 12)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Here it works bot it would be overwritten but the color is not correct

```py
#Plotting Distribution Drugs Numbers per Condition
#plt.style.use('seaborn-whitegrid')
mean=df_calculation["distance_km"].mean()
median = df_calculation["distance_km"].median()
plt.figure(figsize=(11,5))
sns.set_style("white")
ax = sns.distplot(df_calculation["distance_km"],color='lightblue')
ax.axvline(mean, color='r', linestyle='--')
plt.legend({f'Mean = {round(df_calculation["distance_km"].mean(), 2)}':mean})
ax.axvline(median, color='green', linestyle='--')
plt.legend({f'Median = {round(df_calculation["distance_km"].median(), 2)}':median})
plt.box(False)
plt.xlabel("\n Kilometer", fontsize = 12)
plt.ylabel("", fontsize = 12)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `label` parameter inside [`ax.axvline`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.axvline.html). E.g. in your second code block, instead of:

```
ax.axvline(mean, color='r', linestyle='--')
plt.legend({f'Mean = {round(df_calculation["distance_km"].mean(), 2)}':mean})
ax.axvline(median, color='green', linestyle='--')
plt.legend({f'Median = {round(df_calculation["distance_km"].median(), 2)}':median})
```

write:

```
ax.axvline(mean, color='r', linestyle='--', label=f'mean: {mean}')
ax.axvline(median, color='green', linestyle='--', label=f'median {median}')
plt.legend()
```

Result:

[image: plot with legend]